# Changing the code signing certificate

Tags: air, flash-builder, code-signing

I need to change the code signing certificate for my app. I can build the new version with the correct certificate, but users will need to completely uninstall the old version manually before being able to install the new one.

Is there any way in Flash Builder to sign it with both certificates so that the certificate is also updated and further versions can be built and installed as usual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app was originally signed using Air 1.5.2 or above, you can use a process called a 'migration certificate' which allows you to create a chain of trusted certificates. Essentially you sign with your new certificate and migrate with your old certificate, and all should be well.

Unfortunately if your app was created with Air 1.5.1 or below, this isn't available.

You get a period of 6 months from the expiry of the original certificate in which to do the migration signing - more info here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappsflex/WS13ACB483-1711-43c0-9049-0A7251630A7D.html

Comment: I don't know what arguments FB is passing to adt behind the scenes, so is there a way to do this directly from FB?